# How to get rid of page getting unresponsive on Client Side Function call on TextBox onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to **filter** data in a server side control **ListBox** which is having **14K plus** records.

I have a TextBox and I am trying allow anyone to type some text within the **TextBox** and based on which I am trying to show or hide items of my ListBox. My logic is working fine.

> The main problem which I am facing is that my page is going to
>   **unresponsive** mode in both IE and Chrome and which is causing a lot of issue. I am looking
>   for a solution in client side programming to get rid of it.

**ASPX and JS Script**

```js
function SearchListBox() {
    $("#" + $("select[id*='ddl']")[0].id + " option").each(function(){
        if (!(this).text.match("^" + $("input[id*='txtSearch']").val())) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="250px" onkeyup="return SearchListBox();"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:ListBox ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="250px" Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
</td>
```